# Unable to route to a path using router.route()

Tags: javascript, express, middleware, mern

I recently started working on a project I create a route and while I am trying to trigger it using a postman request it just gives the following result in postman.
 [The request that I am sending [image: 1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lat4x.png)

[image: I am getting the following response.]

I am getting the above response.
Please let me know how can I get rid of this issue.
My route looks like this.
`router.route('/newarrivals/demo').post( async(req,res) => { //Code goes in here.... //  });`

Comment: Is `router` mounted at `/api`?

Comment: yes it is. The router is mounted like this app.use('/api',newarrival);

Comment: it is best if you share your code as well. Because it is not possible to debug with one line of code and a screenshot